# How do I force rails to update `updated_at` and run callbacks, even if the record hasn't been changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, updates

I have an endpoint to send updates of pageviews to my API:

```
class PageviewsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @pageview.update!(pageview_params)
    render json: @pageview
  end
end
```

And a callback that re-calculates the duration each time there has been an update:

```
class Pageview < ApplicationRecord
  before_commit :set_duration

  def set_duration
    self.duration = ((updated_at - created_at) * 1000).to_i
  end
end
```

The problem is: sometimes the user is idle, and yet I want to update the duration of the pageview. I'm struggling with this for ours. If I use the `touch`, the `before_commit` doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

`before_commit` is not saved on touch. But you can change the `before_commit` to an `after_commit`

```
class PageView < ApplicationRecord
  after_commit :set_duration

  def set_duration
    update_column(:duration, ((updated_at - created_at) * 1000).to_i)
  end
end
```